# How to import a managed c++ library to C# app (target .net version 3.5)

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio

I created a managed c++ library (wrapper) in visual studio that uses some non-managed c++ library. This wrapped is to be used by c# application which uses .net framework 3.5.

In c++ i add additional dependecies to linker and copy .lib files and .h files of external library to folder where source files exists. I setup 32bit platform and release configuration and build solution. DLL is created so i reference to it in c# application's configuration.

Everything is ok when I use for example .net 4.5 in c# and c++, but c# must be using 3.5 version. I read that I need to build c++ library in older visual studio (i tried 2005 and 2008). I setted V90 build tools and 3.5 .net version and built dll.

When i build c# project no errors are shown, but after running I got such error:
[image: HRESULT: 0x8007007E]

I checked dependecies of my library and that is result (i wrote version next to every item, some of them are 4.0.0.0, some 2.0.0.0). I'm struggling with it few hours and now I just have no idea how to make it working..

[image: Dependiences]

Comment: Trial/Error Solution: Have you tried switching the "embed interop types" to false/true ? Like [here](http://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/wp-upload/images/2010/properties.png)

Comment: Which version of VS are you using exactly? You are using the same version to build both c++ and C# code, right?

Comment: @isi Such option doesn't exist in .net versions older than 4.0. At least it doesn't appear in older ones for me.

Comment: Hm strange, however was just a quick guess. Had strange bugs with that option a while ago which were really hard to detect and had similar if not even same error characteristics. But i might not remember well ;)

Answer (score 2):

The exception class, `FileNotFoundException`, is a little misleading. But the error code (0x8007007E) says more. That's a COM error code that represents a Win32 error code.

How can we tell that? Well, the [structure of COM error codes is described on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms690088.aspx). The `8` indicates an error, and the `7` is the facility, `FACILITY_WIN32`. So, a COM error code of the form `0x8007xxxx` is simply a Win32 error code. The Win32 error code that is wrapped is found in the least significant word. Here it is `0x007E` which is [`ERROR_MOD_NOT_FOUND`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms681382.aspx#ERROR_MOD_NOT_FOUND). The associated text is:

> The specified module could not be found.

That error occurs when the system attempts to load an unmanaged DLL and cannot locate it. The managed assembly would appear to depend upon some unmanaged DLLs, and at least one of them cannot be found. Commonly this could be that:

1. The main unmanaged DLL that the managed assembly wraps cannot be found, or,
2. The MSVC runtime that the unmanaged DLL requires cannot be found.

You'll need to dig a little deeper in the documentation for the managed assembly to work out where the problem is. But hopefully this points you in the right direction. And I hope that I've given you pointers as to how to decode error codes like this in the future.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you may be on wrong track.

There is only one version of .NET can be loaded per process (don't remember the resource where i read this information. for example you can read [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/12/18/1317290.aspx) ). Your error is just correct behaviour

So common solution for this issue - to write assembly for each .NET version. If you look at packages delivered from nuget, you'll see this solution is used there

I think in your current situation you can rewrite your wrapper in unmanaged code and use it with pinvoke technique from C# code. Such solution will make your wrapper .net version independent

Comment: I can do this if it will be the only way, unfortunately it doesn't depends on me. In problem description I made some mistake.

c++ wrapper 64bit, c# app 64 bit - works (.net 4.5) is the only working configuration.

32bit both programs doesn't work even on .net 4.5.

Comment: Maybe I will try to compile c++ wrapper on fresh windows xp system with installed only .net framework 3.5 so it won't dependend on some mscorlib and others in version 4.0.0.0?

Comment: @Lukas hmmm, the situation semms to be unclear for me. Im realy dont know why it works in 64bit mode and doesn't in 32bit. It should work.
As it turned out, starting version 4.0 you can run side-by-side different versions of assemblies (not all, look at table here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee518876(v=vs.110).aspx), but there are no any limitations on 32bit mode

Comment: I've uninstalled .net framework 4.5 and visual studio 2013. Created c++ library in visual studio 2008 and then .net reflector shows that all references have version 2.0.0.0. I've created simple c# application in visual studio 2008 and referenced to my dll and error System.BadImageFormatException still appears (Could not load file or assembly). Fact that my system is 64bit shouldn't have affect on it, right?

![Error snapshot](http://s10.postimg.org/7iwsx4wu0/errrrrr.jpg "Optional title")

Comment: As a variant, you can create new project and test simplified version of your library on a brand new project, just for testing purposes. May be some errors in your current project's configurations cant let you go

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem was on my side, i mean i wasn't copying all required dependencies (one dll). I thought that visual was making something wrong because 64bit version worked without this dll.